# How can I use C#6 to shorten repeated declarations and initialization?

Tags: c#, coding-style, c#-6.0

I've simplified example code below to demonstrate the question. A single `Page` object can have N `Element` objects, in theory there could be hundreds. In order make the code as maintainable as possible, I am asking if there is a way I can declare each `Element` and initialize it on the same line.

The first attempt I made was **B**, but this was annoying/tedious because I had to declare the `Element` in one place and then initialize it in the constructor in a separate part of the class.

The next attempt, and the method I am currently using is **A**. It's a little more code then **B** for each `Element` but it's all one one place. Another advantage (in my situation) is that the `Element` object doesn't actually get created until/if it's needed. The downside (in my opinion of this method) is that when there are 20+ `Element` properties the file get's really long still and it's all copy/paste.

I am looking for a way to declare and initialize each `Element` on one line (and if it can be a singleton like **A** that would be a bonus). **C** is an example of what I would be okay with but does not actually compile for obvious reasons. Is there a way to shorten **B** or rewrite it in a shorter, clearer way potentially with some of the new C#6 features?

---

```
public class Authorization
{
}
```

---

```
public class Element
{
    private Authorization _authorization;

    public Element(Authorization authorization)
    {
        _authorization = authorization;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Page
{
    private Authorization _authorization;

    public Page(Authorization authorization)
    {
        _authorization = authorization;

        ElementTwo = new Element(_authorization);
    }

    // A
    private Element _elementOne;
    public Element ElementOne => _elementOne ?? (_elementOne = new Element(_authorization));

    // B
    public Element ElementTwo { get; private set; }

    // C - Ideal
    // A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Page.Authorization'
    // Cannot access non-static field Authorization in static context
    public Element ElementThree { get; } = new Element(_authorization);
}
```

Comment: You may want to re-read your post, its not making a whole lot of sense.  Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: I don't see where is problem when combining B and C, you can have private setter and initialise property at the same line: `public Element ElementThree { get; private set; } = new Element(Authorization);` It seems like you have different problem since you have code duplication, but from the code provided it's not apparent so we can't help you.

Comment: @CrudaLilium The private setter isn't necessary.  Your "solution" will fail to compile, for exactly the same reason that the OP's code doesn't compile, which they mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Servy You are right, didn't notice it's about dependency in constructor instead of inline declaration.

Comment: Your class `Element` contains a constructor with the name `Field` which isn't possible. It has to be the exact same name of the class.

Comment: @ArnoldPistorius Thanks, I changed the name of the class when I was simplifying the code to post here. It's not a contributing factor to the problem but I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Dictionary and a method for it? Please don't shoot me if [CallerMemberName] isn't working, I didn't compile this code.

```
public class Page {

  private readonly Authorization _auth;
  private readonly IDictionary<string, Element> _elements = new Dictionary<string, Element>();

  public Element ElementOne => GetOrCreateElement();
  public Element ElementTwo => GetOrCreateElement();
  public Element ElementThree => GetOrCreateElement();

  public Page(Authorization auth) {
    _auth = auth;
  }

  private Element GetOrCreateElement([CallerMemberName] string name = null) {
    if(_elements.TryGetValue(name, out var returnElement)) 
      return returnElement;
    var element = new Element(_auth);
    _elements.Add(name, element);
    return element;
  }

}
```